# OpenGL - uniform presence causing shader to be bypassed

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

UPDATE: So it turns out this was due to a bug in the C side of things, causing some of the matrix to become malformed. The shaders are all fine. So if adding uniforms causes weird things to happen, my advice would be to use a debugger to check the value of ALL uniforms and make sure that they are all being set correctly.

---

So I am trying to render depth to a cube map to use as a shadow map, but when I add and use a uniform in the fragment shader everything becomes white as if the shader isn't being used. No warnings or errors are generated when compiling/linking the shader.

The shader program I am using to render the depth map (setting the depth simply to the fragment z position as a test) is as follows:

```
//vertex shader
#version 430

in layout(location=0) vec4 vertexPositionModel;

uniform mat4 modelToWorldMatrix;

void main() {
    gl_Position = modelToWorldMatrix * vertexPositionModel;
}

//geometry shader
#version 430

layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices=18) out;

out vec4 fragPositionWorld;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrices[6];

void main() {
    for (int face = 0; face < 6; face++) {
        gl_Layer = face;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            fragPositionWorld = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
            gl_Position = projectionMatrices[face] * fragPositionWorld;
            EmitVertex();
        }
        EndPrimitive();
    }
}

//Fragment shader
#version 430

in vec4 fragPositionWorld;

void main() {
    gl_FragDepth = abs(fragPositionWorld.z);
}
```

The main shader samples from the cubemap and simply renders the depth as greyscale colour:

```
vec3 lightDirection = fragPositionWorld - pointLight.position;
float closestDepth = texture(shadowMap, lightDirection).r;
finalColour = vec4(vec3(closestDepth), 1.0);
```

The scene is a small cube in a larger cubic room, and renders as expected, dark near z = 0 and the cube projected back onto the wall (The depth map is being rendered from the centre of the room):

Good:

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cdFA.png)

I can move the small cube around and the projection projects correctly onto all the sides of the cubemap. All good so far.

The problem is when I add a uniform to the fragment shader, i.e:

```
#version 430

in vec4 fragPositionWorld;

uniform vec3 lightPos;

void main() {
    gl_FragDepth = min(lightPos.y, 0.5);
}
```

Everything renders as white, same as if the render failed to compile:

Bad:

[image]

gDEBugger reports that the uniform is set correctly (0,4,0) but regardless of what that lightPos is, gl_FragDepth should be set to a value less than 0.5 and appear a shade of grey (which is what happens if I set gl_FragDepth = 0.5 directly), so I can only conclude that the fragment shader is not being used for some reason and the default one is being use instead. Unfortunately I have no idea why.

Comment: Are those the actual fragment shaders you are using? If so, you're not specifying or setting a fragment shader output, so it's not really surprising that you get junk data. Note that `gl_FragDepth` only affects fragment clipping and the depth buffer value, not any lighting calculations (you should be doing those yourself).

Comment: Those are the actual shaders to render to the cubemap framebuffer. The shader that renders to the screen is a fair bit longer. The framebuffer only needs to contain depth information for the light calculation, so that is why only gl_FragDepth is set. I am using http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Point-Shadows as a reference.

Comment: Incidentally, your vertex shader is malformed.
`layout-qualifier interface-qualifier ;` is the proper form, but you have `interface-qualifier layout-qualifier`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Cheers. I corrected it, but it made no difference to the output.

Comment: I didn't think that it would, I just wanted to point that out because it was the only thing that looked wrong. However, now that I look at the final statement in your fragment shader, it raises serious concerns. You are aware that the minimum value in the set of `{ 4, 0.5 }` is **0.5**, right? No matter what value you establish for `lightPos.y` if it's greater than **0.5**, you're going to get the behavior your discussed. Did you perhaps mean to use `max (...)` instead of `min (...)`? You should also probably transform light position into clip-space or window-space before doing this.

Comment: Are you *sure* there were no errors? Because you haven't shown you actually checked - and they don't (necessarily) show up via the normal OpenGL error function. There is a specific function you must call and you should also check the status after compile. See: https://github.com/WilliamKappler/caelumGraphicsSystem/blob/master/src/CGSShader.cpp#L47

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman 'min' is definitely what I wanted. `min(<some large value>, 0.5)` should resolve to **0.5** and produce grey, but it was white instead. Anyway, the shaders are all fine, the bug was in the CPU code. Thanks for the help/advice.